Database Access Issue via Vercel
I'm working on a game website that’s deployed on Vercel using React/Next.js. I'm encountering an issue with securely connecting to my Azure SQL Database. Currently, we set enormous firewall rule for public IP range open(0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255), which poses a big security risk.
Platforms involved:

Frontend: Vercel with React/Next.js (vscode)
Backend: Azure SQL database
Data Access: Prisma ORM

What's the best way to securely connect my Vercel app to Azure SQL Database without exposing it publicly? Are there recommended solutions or best practices for handling this?
I just want give access to all users possible to play my game fast, easy and secure.
Thanks!
Currently, we set enormous firewall rule for public IP range open (0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255), which poses a big security risk.

Unfortunately there's no easy solution to this problem. Because Vercel is running in AWS and outside of Azure, the choices are somewhat limited.
A few things you could do:

Choose very strong username/password: This is what Vercel also recommends though I think it it does not mitigate the problem.
Host your NextJS app in Azure Static WebApp: You can try to host your NextJS app in Azure Static WebApp. However, in my experience the developer experience of hosting NextJS app there is extremely poor and the last time I tried, it just did not work.
Move parts of your code to Azure: Another thing you could do is move the code that talks to Azure resources in Azure and then expose that functionality through some API that you will consume through your NextJS app code running in Vercel.

